# android: Delay call to getView() of an Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-animation

I have a list view and I have implemented an adapter which extends an `ArrayAdapter`
I have overwritten the `getView()` method to implement a custom view.

I am trying to animate the rendering of the List elements to give them a sliding effect, so that the rows appear to slide one by one...
I tried animating it using the following code:

`Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myActivity, R.anim.slide_in_left);
                animation.setDuration(duration);`
                `if(myActivity.flinging)
                    duration+=50;`
                `rowView.startAnimation(animation);`

This does animate the rows but the animation is not smooth.

Is there a way to achieve this? Another way I was thinking of doing this is by delaying the call to getView() but couldn't find a way to do that.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use LayoutAnimationController to provide animations to listview items.

```
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
    animation1.setDuration(300);
    set.addAnimation(animation1);
    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set,1.0f);

    mListView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

For reference you can check this file.

[Example reference](https://code.google.com/p/localguide/source/browse/trunk/src/com/mani/localguide/results.java)